# Watson Visual Recognition - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: java, ibm-watson

I followed the steps in the rebook (http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg248393.pdf) to start a small java app.
I also created a API Key like they described it.

Now im getting an **Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials** message.

```
package vrproject;

//Here you import Watson Java SDK to make it available in your code. 
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.visual_recognition.v3.*;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.visual_recognition.v3.model.*;

public class ClassifyImage {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    VisualRecognition service = new VisualRecognition(VisualRecognition.VERSION_DATE_2016_05_20); 
    service.setEndPoint("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api");

    //Here you replace "your_api_key_here" by the API Key you created in "Creating 
    //a Watson Visual Recognition service instance and getting the API key"
    service.setApiKey("123apikey");

    //Here you add the URL of your image. The image size should not exceed 2MB.
    String imageURL = new
    String("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/watson-developer-cloud/doc-tutorial-downloads/master/visual-recog nition/fruitbowl.jpg");
    ClassifyImagesOptions options = new ClassifyImagesOptions.Builder().url(imageURL).build(); 
    VisualClassification result = service.classify(options).execute(); System.out.println("Classification Results:");
    System.out.println(result);
}

}
```

Error message:

```
    Mär 05, 2020 7:02:23 PM com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService processServiceCall
SCHWERWIEGEND: POST https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?version=2016-05-20&api_key=123apikey, status: 401, error: Unauthorized
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.UnauthorizedException: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.processServiceCall(WatsonService.java:418)
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService$1.execute(WatsonService.java:180)
    at vrproject.ClassifyImage.main(ClassifyImage.java:22)
```

Do you know why I get these error?
I'm not sure if the version it too old, I just used the one from the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redbook was published in 2017, the authentication mechanism it shows is now out of date, and the SDK it uses has been deprecated. You need to modify your code in line with the current API documentation : https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition/visual-recognition-v3?code=java#classify-images

Where at the time of writing the sample code is

```java
IamAuthenticator authenticator = new IamAuthenticator("{apikey}");
VisualRecognition visualRecognition = new VisualRecognition("2018-03-19", authenticator);
visualRecognition.setServiceUrl("{url}");

InputStream imagesStream = new FileInputStream("./fruitbowl.jpg");
ClassifyOptions classifyOptions = new ClassifyOptions.Builder()
  .imagesFile(imagesStream)
  .classifierIds(Arrays.asList("food"))
  .build();
ClassifiedImages result = visualRecognition.classify(classifyOptions).execute().getResult();
System.out.println(result);x
```

where your SDK dependancy will be for

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.watson</groupId>
  <artifactId>ibm-watson</artifactId>
  <version>8.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct service endpoint.  The documentation you linked to shows the endpoint URL: `https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api`

You are using `https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `API_KEY` and `Endpoint` on the Watson Visual Recognition service page.

On the Visual recognition service **Manage** page under credentials, you should see

- API key
- URL

The URL format will be something like this

https://api.REGION.visual-recognition.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/INSTANCEID